# Thumbnail preview of a url using php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a need for getting preview a url over mouse hover, my application is built on php , js and jquery. Although I have an idea of to get to my requirements but am a little confused with the right approach, i checked all the posted question on here but most of them refer to some third party tools or installables. Frnakly i do not want to use them and think i should try one on my own. Please can you guide me through on the best possible step  as per you?

Thanks!

11-Jun-2012
Finally I managed to use Curl and get a preview of the site on a Div placed next to the Link on my site, well now the problem is of fitting the content in the Div ..is there a way that I can adjust the css of the extracted html page in such a way that all the content fits in the fixed height and width of the Div.scaledown option or something? that would scale everything down to the required proportion?

Comment: Ok, so you can do this through using Ajax call, means you can bind an event `mouseover` with anchor tags (where your url resides) and make a ajax call in the handler

Comment: i understood that but how do you suggest i should get the thumbnail of the site?

Comment: by thumbnail i meant the preview!

Comment: you can use iframe, means load the document in the iframe through ajax call and then toggle the iframe visibility at mouseover and mouseout on the url

Comment: @KingKong That's a really bad way of doing this. Many sites use iFrame blocking techniques and if the site has any scripts running in it, they'll still run. Not to mention the huge increase in load time!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, in plain ol' CSS and HTML:

```
.mouseover {
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  display:none;
}
.link {
  position:relative;
}
.link:hover .mouseover {
  display:block;
}
```

Then, in HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="link">Link
  <div style="background:url('<URL HERE>')" class="mouseover"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: hi, i tried but it doesn't seem to work :( ` <a href="#">Link<div style="background:url(http://www.formula1.com/gallery/)" class="mouseover"></div></a>`

Comment: Of course not! the `url` can only be a URL to an image, not just any website. This shows how to display the thumbnail after you already have it.

Comment: yeah...:) sorry just got too excited assuming that it was the fix i needed

Comment: it does, i'll try using it elsewhere..as i really want to display the site thumbnail just like Google ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to get a thumbnail of a webpage and show it on mouse over. To do that, you'll need to either use tools that generate thumbnails or write a PHP script yourself. Here are some tools:

- [websnapr](http://www.websnapr.com/)
- [Website Thumbnail Generator](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/website-thumbnail-generator.php) - This one you can install on your own server

If you want to write your own, check out [imagegrabwindow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php). Note that it requires a Windows server. I don't know if PHP has any other methods to do this. If you're not on a Windows server, you could write a bash script to open a browser and use a [screenshot utility](http://freecode.com/projects/scrot) to take a screenshot and save it to a file for your website to pick up.

You'll also have to make sure to have some sort of cache so you're not doing this every time every user moves their mouse over a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [urlbox.io](https://urlbox.io) for this, here's an example preview thumbnail of this very URL:

https://api.urlbox.io/v1/ca482d7e-9417-4569-90fe-80f7c5e1c781/32040df25d7c57da28ef4da7ce461af00d852653/png?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10970647%2Fthumbnail-preview-of-a-url-using-php-and-javascript&thumb_width=400

You can see that the options passed into the Urlbox API are simply **url**, and **thumb_width** to set the desired width of the thumbnail in pixels, in this case I chose 400 pixels wide.

Now all you got to do is embed it in an `<img>` tag like so:

```html
<img src="https://api.urlbox.io/v1/ca482d7e-9417-4569-90fe-80f7c5e1c781/32040df25d7c57da28ef4da7ce461af00d852653/png?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10970647%2Fthumbnail-preview-of-a-url-using-php-and-javascript&thumb_width=400"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use API to do this. For example [ApiFlash](https://apiflash.com/) has a free plan that you can use up to 100 screenshots per month.

Here is how it would look like with PHP:

```
<?php

$params = http_build_query(array(
    "access_key" => "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY"
    "url" => "https://example.com",
));

$image_data = file_get_contents("https://api.apiflash.com/v1/urltoimage?" . $params);
file_put_contents("screenshot_api_example.jpeg", $image_data);

?>
```

The API has a very [good uptime](http://apiflash.com.isdownorblocked.com) because it's based on AWS Lambda.

[image]